# Selecting all columns, only from row with MAX(date), from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, max

I have 3 tables:

```
events
+--------------------------------+
| id | date       | Name         |
+--------------------------------+
| 1  | 2019-09-29 | First Event  |
| 2  | 2019-10-05 | Second Event |
| 3  | 2019-10-11 | Third Event  |
+--------------------------------+

files
+-----------------------------+
| id | name        | fileSize |
+-----------------------------+
| 1  | 1 file name | 1234786  |
| 2  | 2 file name | 6127833  |
| 3  | 3 file name | 1207834  |
| 4  | 4 file name | 2912873  |
| 5  | 5 file name | 7893465  |
+-----------------------------+

agendaItems
+-----------------------+
| id | eventId | fildId |
+-----------------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1      |
| 2  | 1       | 4      |
| 3  | 1       | 2      |
| 4  | 1       | 5      |
| 5  | 1       | 1      |
| 6  | 2       | 3      |
| 7  | 2       | 4      |
| 8  | 2       | 3      |
| 9  | 2       | 3      |
| 10 | 2       | 2      |
| 11 | 3       | 1      |
| 12 | 3       | 3      |
| 13 | 3       | 5      |
| 14 | 3       | 4      |
| 15 | 3       | 1      |
| 16 | 2       | 2      |
| 17 | 1       | 3      |
| 18 | 3       | 4      |
+-----------------------+
```

If a user searches the files for string **file** and gets back 5 files, how would I also show the latest event (id/date/name) that each file was part of, as well as all the file info?

I've been at this for hours and can't seem get a solution without 3-level-deep subqueries. If I JOIN agendaItems and events with GROUP BY then select MAX(events.date) I can get the right date, but the name and id are not always correct...

The problem seems to be that there is not a direct relationship between the files and the events since one file can be added to multiple agendaItems within an event (e.g. **file 1** is in **event 1** twice in **agendaItem 1 & 5**). All the other posts I've seen on here don't work for this situation.

I feel like I'm missing something really obvious here. Any help would be great.

**Edit 1:**
So far my solution was do a subquery to get all the events that every file was part of, I could then select from that to get the MAX(events.date) for each file, and then those would be left joined to the main query that is getting the file info.

But that seems really inefficient, especially in the long term. In the future I would have to select potentially many many thousands of files/events combinations each time just to get the last time 5 files were part of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should give you the results you want. It `JOIN`s the `files` table to a list of latest event dates for each `fileId` (found by `JOIN`ing `agendaItems` and `events`) and then `JOIN`s that to the `agendaItems` and `events` tables to get the appropriate event name:

```
SELECT f.*, a.Name
FROM files f
JOIN (SELECT fileId, MAX(e.date) AS date
      FROM agendaItems a
      JOIN events e ON e.id = a.eventId
      GROUP BY fileId) m ON m.fileId = f.id
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a.fileId, a.eventId, e.Name, e.date
      FROM agendaItems a 
      JOIN events e ON e.id = a.eventId) a ON a.fileId = f.id AND a.date = m.date
```

Output:

```
id  name            fileSize    Name
1   1 file name     1234786     Third Event
2   2 file name     6127833     Second Event
3   3 file name     1207834     Third Event
4   4 file name     2912873     Third Event
5   5 file name     7893465     Third Event
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5tLSdu6S1fWBnJm88mrpvh/1)

Comment: I think that might work! let me test it out a bit!
What happens if there are two events on the same date, but the file was not part of one of them, how will it know which to choose?

Comment: @user3180004 that won't work... give me a minute to fix it...

Comment: @user3180004 do event dates always increase with `id` values?

Comment: No, the events.id is auto increment and the user picks whichever events.date they want

Comment: @user3180004 see my edit. That should resolve the issue with multiple events on the same day, only one of which pertains to a given file.

Comment: that works! My only concern is if the file is in multiple events on the same day, there's no way to choose a specific event from the group. But I guess that honestly isn't a huge deal, as long as the events are the same day it shouldn't matter which is selected.

Comment: @user3180004 you could work around that by picking the name alphabetically e.g. `SELECT f.*, MIN(a.Name)` and then add `GROUP BY f.id, f.name, f.filesize` to the end